# Codec negotiation in Sip invite

Tags: networking, sip, sdp

I have configured my driving and receiving sip endpoints with the codecs PCMA, PCMU and G729A respectively. When I see the sip invite from the driving end, I  see the codecs in the same order. The 183 session progress from the receiving side shows G729A and the call proceeds with this codec. Why does this happen? I expected the codec negotiated to be PCMA. Is there any  priority involved? Such as payload type?

Answer (score 2):

Each medialine in a SDP offer contains the supported codecs, ordered in decreasing preference.

[RFC3264 5.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3264#section-5.1) states (on SDP offers):

> In all cases, the formats in the "m=" line MUST be listed in order of
> preference, with the first format listed being preferred.  In this
> case, preferred means that the recipient of the offer SHOULD use the
> format with the highest preference that is acceptable to it.

And [RFC3264 6.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3264#section-6.1) (on SDP answers):

> Although the answerer MAY list the formats in their desired order of
> preference, it is RECOMMENDED that unless there is a specific reason,
> the answerer list formats in the same relative order they were
> present in the offer.  In other words, if a stream in the offer lists
> audio codecs 8, 22 and 48, in that order, and the answerer only
> supports codecs 8 and 48, it is RECOMMENDED that, if the answerer has
> no reason to change it, the ordering of codecs in the answer be 8,
> 48, and not 48, 8.  This helps assure that the same codec is used in
> both directions.

The following lines are taken from a SDP offer; the sender announces he supports codecs 8, 0 and 101. He prefers 8 (PCMA) over 0 (PCMU).

```
m=audio 6200 RTP/AVP 8 0 101
a=rtpmap:8 PCMA/8000
a=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000
a=rtpmap:101 telephone-event/8000
```

The receiver will decide which codec(s) will actually be used and sends this in the SDP answer. He will leave out the codecs he doesn't support and may change the relative order of the remaining codecs (though not recommended).